# Unexpected results in browser

Tags: html, css

Can somebody please help me understand why I am seeing what I am seeing?

[Code](http://jsfiddle.net/vBAYA/):

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <style>
            #Viewport { width:50%; height:50%; margin: 0 auto; position: relative; background-color: blue; }
            #one { position: absolute; width: 5%; height: 70%; background-color: green;}
            #two { width: 5%; float: right; }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="Viewport">
            <section id="one">
                <p>hi</p>
            </section>
            <section id="two">
                <p>hi</p>
            </section>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I expect to have widths of `5%`, not ~`20%`. I expect to see colored backgrounds. This is weird. What gives?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `overflow:auto` to `#Viewport`

```
#Viewport {
     width:50%;
     height:50%;
     margin: 0 auto;
     position: relative;
     background-color: blue;
     overflow:auto;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/AhuWv/)**

Since you floated `#two` you removed it from the flow of the document. `overflow:auto` restores the expected behavior.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you! How can I have that green div pop out of its parent div and give it a bigger height in percentages? I've been at this for days with no avail.

Comment: Oh you're awesome. Thanks so much. Is it possible to make that green div extend to the very bottom-edge of the browser window, without exceeding it?

Comment: :-O Thank you again :-) I bow down to you sir lol (I will accept as answer when the timer lets me.)

Answer (score 2):

Also, remember that the [`percentage` value](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#percentages) is always relative to another value, and because you're declaring `50%` height on the descendant without specifying any other percentage heights further up the DOM (and for the root element) the percentage height won't work.

Add `html, body {height: 100%:}`

[**Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/gpKNC/)

Comment: +1 All of the elements with background colors have a height of 0.